# WCF with Kerberos Authentication: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authentication, kerberos

I am attempting to perform Kerberos authentication from a Client App (Windows Forms) to a WCF Web Service on one Windows 2008 R2 server running under IIS, which in-turn calls another WCF service running on another Windows 2008 R2 server also running under IIS. I've seen this referred to this as a Kerberos Double-Hop Authentication.

When I locate the two web services on the same Windows 2008 R2 server then our double-hop authentication works fine. However, when we move the second WCF service to a different server the authentication fails between the two web services. I do not know what causes this problem which may be a configuration issue, or something in our server/network set-up. Client and servers all exist in the same domain.

Here is more detail of what I have done so far. I've tried many of the suggestions in other related topics/questions about this issue, but no joy so far.

- I have created a Windows Form client application that connects to a
  WCF web service (I will refer to this as the Middle service), and
  return the user name of the logged in user to the client app from the
  service.
- In the client app.config (see below) we have specified 'Windows'
  authentication (pls see below for config).
- The Middle service runs on our server 'SERVER1'.
- The Middle service returns the User Name fine to the client app,
  therefore the Middle service authentication must be working fine.
- I have another method in the Middle service that calls another WCF
  web service (I will refer to this second service as the End service),
  and again Windows authentication is specified on the binding from
  Middle service to End service. If I locate the End service on the
  same server as the Middle service then again authentication works as
  expected, and the User name for the logged in user (ie: me) is
  returned to the client app from the End service, via the Middle
  service. However, if I locate the End service on a different server
  (SERVER2) the authentication (double hop) fails, 'Inner exception:The
  request for security token could not be satisfied because
  authentication failed.'
- The Client app, Middle service and End service all exist in the same
  Domain (MYDOMAIN).
- I am using a service account (MYDOMAIN\MY-HOST_ACCOUNT) to run both
  Middle and End service, and created a Service Principal Name (SPN)
  for this called 'HTTP/SERVER1.int.mydomain.com'. I have also trusted
  this service account, and the computer/machine 'SERVER1' for Kerberos
  delegation in Active Directory (Trust this user/computer for
  delegation to any service). The Bindings use 'Message' security mode
  and this is specified in the Web Service bindings.
- I have included the Client app.config and both Web Service
  web.configs (pls see below).
- I have tried a variety of different config settings, and these
  current settings work fine when the services are located on the same
  server, but the error occurs when the services are on different
  servers. I have tried both 'true' and 'false' for
  'negotiateServiceCredential', but believe this needs to be 'true'. I
  get a different error message when this is set to false (The
  authentication modes using Kerberos do not support the impersonation
  level 'Delegation'. Specify identification or impersonation).

Hopefully someone who has dealt with 'double hop' WCF Kerberos authentication before may recognise this issue and be able to assist me.

Many thanks

CLIENT APP CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMiddleService">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DelegationBehavior">
              <clientCredentials>
                <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
              </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://SERVER1/KerberosMiddleService/MiddleService.svc"
              behaviorConfiguration="DelegationBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMiddleService" contract="KerberosMiddleService.IMiddleService"
              name="WSHttpBinding_IMiddleService">
            <identity>
              <servicePrincipalName value="HTTP/SERVER1.int.mydomain.com"/>
              <userPrincipalName value="MYDOMAIN\MY-HOST_ACCOUNT@int.mydomain.com"/>
            </identity>
          </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

MIDDLE SERVICE WEB CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEndService">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
         </binding>
          <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEndService1">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" establishSecurityContext="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DelegationBehavior">
         <clientCredentials>
           <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" />
         </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://SERVER2/endservice/endservice.svc" 
                behaviorConfiguration="DelegationBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEndService" contract="KerberosEndService.IEndService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IEndService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://SERVER1/kerberosendservice/endservice.svc" 
                behaviorConfiguration="DelegationBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEndService1" contract="BT01_KerberosEndService.IEndService"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IEndService1">
      </endpoint>
    </client>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

END SERVICE WEB CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

A SECTION OF THE WCF STACK TRACE

```
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---&amp;gt; System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.FaultException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)</ExceptionString></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent><E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-02T21:04:14.4059347Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{acfc80d6-b119-4f57-aaf2-65f1319b9fca}" /><Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="1432" ThreadID="43" /><Channel/><Computer>SERVER1</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-NZ/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/KerberosMiddleService-6-130698038017642990</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The caller was not authenticated by the service.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.GetNextOutgoingMessage(Message incomingMessage, T negotiationState)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---&amp;gt; System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you need to add another SPN for the end service as well:

```
HTTP/SERVER2.int.mydomain.com MYDOMAIN\MY-HOST_ACCOUNT)
HTTP/SERVER2 MYDOMAIN\MY-HOST_ACCOUNT)
```

It is best to specify both FQDN and  Netbios name. Ensure that you don't have duplicate SPN's otherwise Kerberos authentication wont work. Add the SPN's as delegation targets to the domain account (this might not be needed since you are using the same domain account for both servers).

Since the MiddleService needs to impersonate/delegate to the EndService, you need to give the domain account the privileges to do so using the local security policies - Local Policies - User Rights Assignment:

**Act as part of the operating system**

This user right allows a process to impersonate any user without authentication. The process can therefore gain access to the same local resources as that user.

**Impersonate a client after authentication**

Assigning this privilege to a user allows programs running on behalf of that user to impersonate a client.

Remember to change your IIS application settings to use the application pool credentials so that the domain account is used for authentication.

Comment: Many thanks, yes, this all helped. I also had to add allowNtlm="false in the web.config for the endpoint behavior as follows: <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" allowNtlm="false" />